How to serve files from S3 with an header / cookie / param / whatever (like a bearer token) control?
I have a bucket with public access on all files on it. I would like to restrict access to a file only to people who have the link to the concerned file plus a token. It can be a header, can be a cookie, a query param, whatever, a thing in addition which can be checked and which is unique per file. Any idea on how to do it ?

Use presigned URLs. It allows to publicly access to private files without exposing the other files. And can expires at a chosen duration.
